# Most frequent value in SQL colum Jpa

Tags: java, sql, jpa

i have this method here i  want find the most frequent value in a given column in an SQL table,
the Sql code is working fine when i am trying it on MSSQL but when i am trying to return the values it is giving me **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to BLL.Perdoruesi**

```
   public  Perdoruesi repeatedUsername() throws PerdoruesiException{
        String sql ="   select p.Username ,count(*) as nor from Perdoruesi p\n" +
"        group by Username\n" +
"          having count(*) =(select max(nor) from \n" +
"            (select Username,count(*) as nor from Perdoruesi group by Username) Perdoruesi)";
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        try{
            return (Perdoruesi)query.getSingleResult();
        }catch(NoResultException e){
            throw new PerdoruesiException("..");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` indicates that the type returned is an array.

Comment: How can  i access those 2 values that this query returns?

Comment: Assigning the result to an array and index the array. I would use `.getClass()` and debug or log to be sure of the exact types being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
 public  String []repeatedUsername() throws PerdoruesiException{
        String sql ="   select p.Username ,count(*) as nor from Perdoruesi p\n" +
"        group by Username\n" +
"          having count(*) =(select max(nor) from \n" +
"            (select Username,count(*) as nor from Perdoruesi group by Username) Perdoruesi)";
        String p = null;
        int numri = 0;
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();

        for(Object [] obj : list){
                 p = (String)obj[0];
                 numri = (int) obj[1];
        }

                return new String[]{p,String.valueOf(numri)};
    }
```